# PHP curl post works but not returning data

Tags: php, curl, response

Hello I have a curl class that sends a post to a remote server.
On that server I get data from a db and echo it out. The data is collected but
I the sending curl server gets not data back. Here is my code:

```
$ch = curl_init();

self::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_URL] = $this->url;
self::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_POST] = true;
self::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = $this->get_data();

curl_setopt_array($ch, self::$CURL_OPTS);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

Nothing echos though even though it sends the data to the remote server.

This is a curl class so if you need more code for help let me know.

EDIT*********************
I have that and its still not working. here is my class.

> ```
> <?php
> ```

```
  /**
 * install, update, download, api
 */
abstract class Http {
protected $url;
protected $params;
protected $data;
protected $files;

protected $api_client  = 1;
protected $api_key     = 'xxx';


protected static $CURL_OPTS = array(
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 0,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 60,
    CURLOPT_POST           => false,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array()
);

public function set_url($url) {
    $this->url = $url;
}

public function get_url() {
    return $this->url;
}

public function set_data($data) {
    $this->data = $data;
}

public function get_data() {
    return $this->data;
}

public function push() {
    $ch = curl_init();

    self::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_URL] = $this->url;
    self::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_POST] = true;
    self::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = $this->get_data();
    self::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER] = 1;

    curl_setopt_array($ch, self::$CURL_OPTS);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;
}

public function pull() {
    $ch = curl_init();

    self::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_URL] = $this->url;
    self::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER] = 1;

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;
}

abstract protected function check();
abstract protected function install();
abstract protected function update();
abstract protected function download();
abstract protected function api();
```

}

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer - I showed exactly what you need to change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the data as the result of `curl_exec`, you need to set option `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to `true`.

From the documentation:

```
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER    TRUE to return the transfer as
                          a string of the return value of
                          curl_exec() instead of outputting
                          it out directly.
```

**EDIT:** Looking at your curl class, you have this code:

```
protected static $CURL_OPTS = array(
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 0,       // this line ensures that you do NOT get the data back
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 60,
    CURLOPT_POST           => false,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array()
);
```

change it to

```
protected static $CURL_OPTS = array(
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,       // this line ensures that you do get the data back
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 60,
    CURLOPT_POST           => false,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array()
);
```

Comment: Yes but I override that in the push() method. It sets it to one.

Comment: @Naterade Check your return status - is it 200?  If not, you may not get anything back.

Answer (score 2):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```